# ngOnInit not called after initial sign in

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am building a web app using **Angular *4.4.6***. The project is set up via the **Angular CLI** and uses **AngularFire2** to talk with a **Firestore** back end and **FirebaseAuth**.

I have several modules set up and am successfully reading/writing/displaying data and navigating around so I assume that fundamentally there are no problems. However, I have found one bug that I can't seem to fix...

On successful log in I call `this.router.navigate(['/groups']);`. This navigates to a new module but `ngOnInit` never fires on the component mapped to that path.

The constructor of the component *does* fire as do methods called within that constructor. The static content in the template renders (dynamic stuff from services etc does not) but `ngOnInit` is never called.

If I refresh the page everything works fine. If I then navigate away to a different section and then navigate back it also works fine.
It seems to be something about that first time navigation immediately after login. Perhaps a timing thing? Something to do with zones?

Can anyone shed any light on what is going on here?

Cheers all

> **EDIT - More Specific Detail**

After some fiddling, this appears to be related to the specific way I am triggering navigation.
If I log in an then manually click a button to trigger `this.router.navigate(['/groups']);` then all is fine.
However, I am using `AngularFireAuth` like this:

```
constructor(
    public afAuth:AngularFireAuth,
    private router:Router
  ){
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
      if(user != null){
        this.router.navigate(['/groups']);
      }
    });
  }
```

My intention being to navigate to groups section as soon as an authorised user is returned. This is where it fails - with `ngOnInit` not firing as described above.
I tried just adding a timer to wait for a few seconds before triggering router but it makes no difference.

So, what's the difference between logging in and navigating as soon as the auth user is returned and logging in then manually navigating??

Comment: What version of router are you using?

Comment: Could you provide the code that is inside the `ngOnInit`?

Comment: `ngOnInit` is called after `ngOnChanges` is called. `ngOnChanges` is called after input values changed. With routed components there can't be any input bindings, therefore `ngOnInit` shouldn't expecting to be called.

Comment: Following Gunter's comment, you could call a private function from the constructor that has all the code you currently have in your ngOnInit().

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This is incorrect. ngOnInit is called in route components. Route components follow lifecycle but there may be differences due to how router outlet works, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47268066/3731501 .

Comment: It might be called, but you shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Why? You should, but also should keep in mind how the router works. I'm positive that the problem is that component instance is reused with default route reuse strategy. It's not that ngOnInit is not called but the component is not re-compiled. There may be a dupe for this question.

Comment: @rrd I'm using Router 4.2.4

Comment: Not sure what you mean with recompiled. If you use `ngOnInit` in a routed component, you use it for the wrong purpose and you are on your own. Use rather `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: @WesleyCoetzee and @GünterZöchbauer All I have in ngOnInit currently is a `console.log()`. It definitely does not fire when I initially navigate to the route but does fire if I then refresh the page

Comment: @rrd I can indeed move my code from ngOnInit to the constructor however when I do this my bindings in the template fail to render. This could be unrelated though - am investigating now.

Comment: @estus I did find a couple of similar questions but they were about coming back to a component after initial compilation as you mentioned. My issue seems to be on the first initialisation only and works fine from there on.

Comment: @popClingwrap You need to provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the issue.

Comment: @estus - I know. I was hoping (naively) to get a simple answer and avoid it as it's gonna be a real pain to strip back but I will have to do it now. Watch this space :)

Comment: This could be something like the question I've linked above. It's not a common problem, to my knowledge. ngOnInit is expected to work in route components.

Comment: @estus It seems like the problem is tied somehow to `AngularFireAuth` or the actual Googe auth process (see my edit). I wasn't able to get AngularFire or Google sign in working in plunker though so I dunno what to do about providing an example. If the edited question doesn't produce any suggestions I think I'll just have to hack around this and come back to it down the line. Cheers for your input :)

Comment: The question I've mentioned addresses that, and the answer was provided, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47268066/3731501 . The question can be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @estus Sorry, maybe I am being dumb but I can't see a solution still. It's not that the component does not have time to call `ngOnInit` as in the article, I never navigate away from it. It is constructed and the static parts of the template are rendered but `ngOnInit` never fires and bindings in the template never resolve. If this is a router issue I don't see why it works when `router.navigate` is called from a user action (click) but not when called from a listener on the auth state. Apologies if I'm missing the point here :s

Comment: This presumably happens because onAuthStateChanged callback is *synchronously* called in constructor, and so is router.navigate, at least this is the only scenario I'm aware of where ngOnInit may not be called. Synchronous router.navigate call aborts component compilation and this is what the answer says. Does this happen if you comment router.navigate ? It likely should. If does not, consider providing MCVE that can replicate the issue. I'm not sure what the solution would be in your case. You likely need to change how auth works in your app.

Comment: @estus I painstakingly reconstructed pretty much my entire build in stackblitz for MCVE but could not reproduce the issue. I downloaded the build from stackblitz and ran it from the angular cli and the error comes back. Hey Ho down the rabbit hole I go

Comment: I'd say that's creepy, heh. Make sure you're running latest CLI. Did you get same result with JIT (ng serve) and AOT (ng build)?

Comment: @estus Updated CLI, moved to Angular 5, tried `ng serve`, `ng build`, `ng build --prod`. In all cases (except the version on StackBlitz) `ngOnInit` is not called when the component is reached by `router.navigate` called from a listener attached to `onAuthStateChanged`. I'm stumped - gonna start looking for hacks now.

Comment: Did you try to actually detect if the problem is that router.navigate is synchronously called, as it would be the source of the problem that should be addressed? E.g. `console.time('route')` in constructor and `console.timeEnd('route')` in onAuthStateChanged callback.

Comment: @estus Do you mean in the constructor from my code example above? This produces a result of however many ms I wait before triggering login. Adding code to the the constructor of the targeted '/groups' component has no effect as it is never called