# angular 4. remove a component in the constructor based on an if

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add protection to components.
If a user doesn't have permission to see this component it wont be rendered.

I have tried putting my `if` in the constructor and return `false` but it still renders.

I also added the `if` to the template itself but then I didn't see the view but the component is still alive and it adds complexity to the code as I need to maintain several places of the same `if`.

Is there a way to tell the component to not render at all ?

```js
 constructor( private userService: UserService) {
    if (this.userService.isAllowed("see_trade_groups") === false) {
           return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component compilation lifecycle is handled by Angular compiler, so a component is unable to control its own lifecycle, and it should be controlled from the outside.

A common way to handle this is to use router. The lifecycle in route components differs from regular components because it's handled by router; they are attached to `<router-outlet>` component. It's possible to [prevent compilation in route components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267448/angular-4-can-ondestroy-be-run-without-the-oninit-ever-being-triggered) but not in regular components.

Otherwise this should be handled with a directive. `ngIf` is built-in way to prevent the compilation of regular components.

So it becomes

```
<foo *ngIf="userService.isAllowed('see_trade_groups')"></foo>
```

Since this requires to inject `userService` to parent component every time it's needed, this will result in a lot of boilerplate code. An appropriate solution is to create a directive that behaves similarly to `ngIf` - or extend it to provide desired functionality:

```
import {Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {NgIf, NgIfContext} from '@angular/common';

...

@Directive({
    selector: '[role]'
})
class Role extends NgIf {
    @Input() role: string;

    constructor(
        viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        templateRef: TemplateRef<NgIfContext>
        public userService: User
    ) {
        super(viewContainer, templateRef);
    }

    ngOnChanges({ role }: SimpleChanges) {
        this.ngIf = this.userService.isAllowed(role);
        // can also subscribe to some observable to add/remove a component any time 
    }
}
```

Which is used like:

```
<foo *role="'see_trade_groups'"></foo>
```

Notice that `Role` is `*` structural directive. This allows it to control the compilation of an element it was specified on, similarly to how `ngIf` and `ngFor` do.

Answer (score 3):

For that purpose you can see **[CanActivate](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwimi9KbievYAhWKFiwKHQW6BOgQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2Fapi%2Frouter%2FCanActivate&usg=AOvVaw2z79QXpqG1oYWBOfI3-SPa)**. Put it on the component `route` and it will do the job you want.

In that you can write a logic, based on which the route will be navigated or not.

Comment: i need it on a component based and not a a route based as i can have many components on the same route

Comment: You have many components and want to show some and hide some based on condition ?

Comment: if i put the ngif it works but the component still do api calls as only the template doesn't renders . then i need to add if on all the component hooks . something i rely want to avoid

Comment: The *ngIf should be **around** your component, not inside. If your component still make HTTP calls, it's either that, or you forgot to unsubscribe from your observables.